# Java Finding Max Element

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm attempting to find the maximum element without using

```
import java.util.Collections

public static int maxArrayListValue(int[] arrayList) {
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int[] qqq : arrayList) {
        for (int vvv : qqq) {
            if (vvv > maxVal) {
                maxVal = vvv;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}
```

But I always get an error in `for (int[] qqq : arrayList)`

`(Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type int to int[])`

After Changing it to "`for (int qqq : arrayList)`"  Still got an error on the second code for (int vvv : qqq)

`(Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhanced for loop takes each value from the provided Collection and processes it.

Your code should be:

```
public static int maxArrayListValue(int[] arrayList) {
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int vvv : arrayList) {
        if (vvv > maxVal) {
            maxVal = vvv;
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`arrayList` is a 1-D array , so `for (int[] qqq : arrayList)` is wrong

use `for (int qqq : arrayList)`

Comment: After doing it still have an error but on the next line which is "for (int vvv : qqq) " can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int maxArrayListValue(int[] arrayList) {
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int qqq : arrayList) {
        if(qqq > maxVal){
            maxVal = qqq;
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the variable `qqq` as an array of Integers.
The reason this declaration is incorrect is because `arrayList` is a one dimensional array meaning it contains Integers and not arrays of Integers.
Assuming that you wish to check for each integer within the `arrayList` parameter in the method, you'll need to replace the `int[]` declaration with `int` so that it's checking for each Integer rather than for each array of Integers.
Regarding the other error, that nested `for` loop isn't required. By saying:

```
for (int vvv : qqq)
```

with `qqq` declared as an Integer, you're essentially saying "for each integer in an integer" which doesn't make sense - hence the error.
You can use `qqq` instead of `vvv` where you're checking the validity of it against the `maxVal`.
To fix both problems you're having, here's the corrected method:

```
public static int maxArrayListValue(int[] arrayList) {
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int vvv : arrayList) {
        if (vvv > maxVal) {
            maxVal = vvv;
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int maxArrayListValue(int[] arrayList) {
    int maxVal = 0;
    for (int[] i = 0; i < arrayList.length-1; i ++) {
            if (arrayList[i] > maxVal) {
                maxVal = vvv;
            }
    }
    return maxVal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using Streams? Though an `int[]` won't work, consider using `Integer[]` or directly use a `List<Integer>`

```
Arrays.asList(arrayList).stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
      .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```